# Is something with my logic in this ADO.NET code? it is always return false?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

This is a simple function that returns TRUE if the user exists in the users table, false otherwise.

For some reason it is always return false, I even removed the WHERE clause and I still get false?  (a manual check in query analyzer tells me I have lots of rows?)

```
Public Shared Function DoesUserExist(ByVal userID As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim retValue As Boolean

    retValue = False

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())

        'Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT user_ID FROM users WHERE user_ID = @userID", conn)
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT user_ID FROM users", conn)


        cmd.Parameters.Add("@userID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userID
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        conn.Open()

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()


        'If Not reader Is Nothing Then
        '    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<br>Null")
        'End If

        If reader.Read() Then

            retValue = True

        End If


        conn.Close()

        cmd.Dispose()

    End Using


    retValue = False



    Return retValue

End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

You are setting retValue to false before exiting. That's the problem.

This is the proper code:

```
...

    If reader.Read() Then

        retValue = True

    Else

        retValue = False

    End If


    conn.Close()

    cmd.Dispose()

End Using

Return retValue

....
```

Comment: That's doable as well. I'm just pointing out the difference between both codes.

Answer (score 2):

it could be the line at the end that sets "retValue" to false?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you set retValue to false before you return.

It doesn't matter what you set it to before - it will always be false at the end of the function by these lines:

```
retValue = False
Return retValue
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in the code.

1: You are not using the `@userID` parameter in the query. Therefore it always returns all users, and the only case that the result would be empty is if there are no users at all.

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT user_ID FROM users where user_ID = @UserID", conn)
```

2: You are setting the `retValue` variable to `false` again just before the `return` statement. Therefore the method always returns `false` regardless of result from checking the data reader.

Also, you should call `Dispose` on the data reader.

Answer (score 0):

You set retValue to false right before you return it, and there's no other Return statement in your code, so it doesn't matter what happens before.  Remove the last retValue = False.

You want something like this:

```
Public Shared Function DoesUserExist(ByVal userID As Integer) As Boolean

    Dim retValue As Boolean

    retValue = False

    Using conn As New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
         // conditionally set retValue = true, etc.
    End Using

    Return retValue

End Function
```